# Getting links from a website

Tags: android, curl

I have a website (say xyz.com) which has been created with `WordPress`. I have a number of pages and sub-pages within it which follow the url structure: `xyz.com/pageN/subpageM/`

I am required to build an Android app around this which:
1. Goes to the website xyz.com
2. Queries the website for a list of pages. - page1 through pageN.
3. Displays the pages in a set layout. If the user clicks on a page, then sub-pages are queried and displayed. Clicking on a sub-page goes to the content.

I have been looking at doing this with either `cURL` or `http` connections within `Android` but have so far come up with a blank.

My question(s):
1. How do I get a list of pages 'N' levels down from the main website?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an external tool like [yql](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/). In that way you don't need to scrap all the html code in the device searching for the pages.
The response is like a webservice and you can get the results of the query as xml or json